# Dropdown of wxPython combobox doesn't work on popup window

Tags: python, wxpython

When I put a combo box on wxPython popup window, dropdown function doesn't work.

My example code is this.

```
import wx

class TestPopup(wx.PopupWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.PopupWindow.__init__(self, parent = parent)

        self.popUp = wx.Panel(self, size = (200,200))
        self.popUp.SetBackgroundColour("white")

        self.st = wx.StaticText(self.popUp, -1, " Select Comport", pos=(10,10))
        self.selCom = wx.ComboBox(self.popUp, -1, pos=(85, 50), choices=["Com1", "Com2"])

        self.mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mySizer.Add(self.popUp)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.mySizer)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "ComboBox Test", size = (300,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.selComButton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Select Comport")
        self.selComButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.selectPopUp)
        self.selCom = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, pos = (85, 50),choices=["Com1", "Com2"])


    def selectPopUp(self, event):

        win = TestPopup(self.GetTopLevelParent())
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        pos = btn.ClientToScreen((0, 0))
        sz = btn.GetSize()
        win.Position(pos, (0, sz[1]))

        win.Show(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In the code, combo box in main frame works well. But, in the popup window, which is shown when 'select Comport' button is clicked, combobox doesn't work.

What's wrong with this?

[image]

It works well.

[image]

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox certainly works in a popup window under Linux, so it's difficult to address your question directly. However, I would suggest that in this case, you might well be better served, if you were to use a `Dialog` rather than a `PopUpWindow`, as it will do the heavy lifting for you.
For example:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "Communication Port", size = (300,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.selComButton = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Select Comport")
        self.selComButton.SetToolTip("Select Comport")
        self.selComButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.selectPopUp)

    def selectPopUp(self, event):
        dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,"Pick a com port", "Com ports",["Com1","Com2","Com3","Com4"],wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            res = dlg.GetStringSelection()
            self.selComButton.SetLabel(res)
        dlg.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: My solution is another frame, instead of popup window. yours looks better than mine...